# How to redirect a domain pointing to Heroku hosting to www (with SSL)

Tags: heroku, dns, namecheap

my domain example.com is accessible through https://www.example.com

http://example.com and http://www.example.com both redirect to https://www.example.com
and this is a good news

the redirect just can't work with SSL , so https://example.com make timeout and not accessible for users

surely , that's not good - I need https://example.com also to redirect to https://www.example.com

Namecheap customer support told me , that's not possible as the root domain refers to external hosting , finally as they said

I had to make this redirect from Heroku side , how can I make something like this

I think Heroku does not have this option , any tricky solutions ?

please note , adding a CNAME record pointing to Heroku will damage my email hosting with Namecheap , so this solution is not possible

or if there's other solution to add this CNAME and host my emails with external service - not sure how ?

Answer (score 0):

If you through the heroku documents there is restriction on root/naked domain pointing, i would suggest to use pointDns.